# How to loop over ansible_devices[elements]

Tags: ansible

I can gather facts from a host and I can see my drives. How can I use the ansible_devices variable to acquire just the drive (sda, sdb, etc)?

I'm trying to do something similar to this:

```
tasks:
- debug: msg={{item.mount}}
  with_items: ansible_mounts
```

I tried the following debug message but the only variable I was able to see was just one drive:

```
debug: msg={{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]["ansible_devices"] }}
```

.

```
 "ansible_devices": {
        "sda": {
            "holders": [],
            "host": "Serial Attached SCSI controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic SAS2008 PCI-Express Fusion-MPT SAS-2 [Falcon] (rev 03)",
            "model": "Crucial_CT480M50",
            "partitions": {
                "sda1": {
                    "sectors": "2097152",
                    "sectorsize": 512,
                    "size": "1.00 GB",
                    "start": "2048"
                },
                "sda2": {
                    "sectors": "8388608",
                    "sectorsize": 512,
                    "size": "4.00 GB",
                    "start": "2099200"
                },
                "sda3": {
                    "sectors": "927213568",
                    "sectorsize": 512,
                    "size": "442.13 GB",
                    "start": "10487808"
                }
            },
            "removable": "0",
            "rotational": "0",
            "scheduler_mode": "cfq",
            "sectors": "937703088",
            "sectorsize": "4096",
            "size": "3.49 TB",
            "support_discard": "33553920",
            "vendor": "ATA"
        },
        "sdb": {
            "holders": [],
            "host": "Serial Attached SCSI controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic SAS2008 PCI-Express Fusion-MPT SAS-2 [Falcon] (rev 03)",
            "model": "Micron_M500_MTFD",
            "partitions": {
                "sdb1": {
                    "sectors": "1875380224",
                    "sectorsize": 512,
                    "size": "894.25 GB",
                    "start": "4096"
                }
            },
            "removable": "0",
            "rotational": "0",
            "scheduler_mode": "cfq",
            "sectors": "1875385008",
            "sectorsize": "4096",
            "size": "6.99 TB",
            "support_discard": "33553920",
            "vendor": "ATA"
        },
```

Comment: If you know which drive you are looking for you can reference it exactly - hostvars[inventory_hostname]["ansible_devices"]["sda"]
You could also iterate each drive - 
with_items: hostvars[inventory_hostname]["ansible_devices"]

Comment: ??? you already see two drives `sda` and `sdb` in `ansible_devices`.  What output do you expect?

Comment: @yaegashi I changed my question.

Comment: Finally I got your point.  You should have shown the problematic output as well as expected output in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are experiencing a problem in module argument parsing.  Try quoting the argument like this:

```
- debug: msg="{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]["ansible_devices"] }}"
```

It would be better to use `var` instead of `msg` of [`debug` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/debug_module.html):

```
- debug: var=hostvars[inventory_hostname]["ansible_devices"]
```

And I always recommend to pass module arguments as a dict to decrease complexity of quoting:

```
- debug:
    var: hostvars[inventory_hostname]["ansible_devices"]
```

You can get an array of device names using `keys()` as in @ydaetskcoR's answer:

```
- debug:
    var: hostvars[inventory_hostname]["ansible_devices"].keys()
```

Comment: if you don't mind me asking, how would you loop through the partitions of each device?

Answer (score 0):

You can see that `ansible_devices` is a dictionary of all of the different devices attached to the host thus you can easily get just a list of all the device names by using `.keys()`.

Also, when testing to see what a variable is being set to you should use `debug`'s `var` rather than `msg`.

So your debug command should be:

```
debug: var={{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]["ansible_devices"].keys() }}
```

Comment: thanks for an answer but the debug message spits out only a single device. How can I loop through it like it my example. 
`TASK: [test] ***********************************************************
ok: [server-1] => {
    "msg": "[u'sdd',"
}`

Comment: Apologies, only just saw your comment. I simply tagged `.keys()` to the end of your example but, as explained by @yaegashi, you should be using `var` instead of `msg` here. I've updated my answer accordingly.